# SVN compare with context menu is disabled - IntelliJ

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I recently switched from Eclipse to IntelliJ. 
My project uses SVN. 
In IntelliJ I can commit or update code just fine. However, when I want to compare the current code base with the latest from repository, in Context Menu, `Subversion > Compare with Latest Repository Version`, this menu is disabled. Same for other Compare With menu or Show Current Revision.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the file is recognized by SVN?

Comment: @Makoto: which file you are talking abt? For files in the project, I can commit or update normally (right click, subversion > Commit Directory or Update Directory). But I can not compare with remote repository. This option is grey.

Comment: Are you sure that IntelliJ recognizes that the file is recognized by SVN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA does not currently support the "Compare" actions on directories for Subversion. You can invoke "Compare" on individual files, and you can use the Changes | Repository view to see the latest commits to the repository.

The corresponding feature request is http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-55335

Comment: I see. That's right, the context menu is enabled when I only select individual file. How can they not have this capability.